# Multiple separators and mixed quotations in CSV and Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a specific CSV file, I think this is a standard how PHP works because it's coming from PHP code.

I'm trying to use pandas to remove certain columns (200+ columns), but need to preserve the quotations in both header line and all other lines.

shorted header line:

```
name, "Full Name", "Suggested Name", id
```

(so spaces are escaped with double quotes in the header line)

And data:

```
blah, "Very, Blah Line", "Not Suggested", 2
```

So have commas and spaces within the column, and such is escaped with quotes.

If I use pandas read_scv, it reads the data correctly, but then saves everything with quotes, meaning changes header line to:

```
"name", "Full Name", "Suggested Name", "id"
```

And same with data.

This breaks some of our environments, and I can't have that in CSV.

If I use no quotation, then it takes all the quotations out from header line, and other lines, where then spaces become a problem.

Any suggestion welcome here.

Answer (score 0):

Use the correct [quoting-constant](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.QUOTE_ALL) from the module csv in your `pd.to_csv(...)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)-call.

You most probably need either `QUOTE_MINIMAL` or `QUOTE_NONNUMERIC`:

- [QUOTE_MINIMAL](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL) : quotes only where needed
- [QUOTE_NONNUMERIC](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC) : quotes all non-numerics

You probably need QUOTE_MINIMAL (because `blah` is not quoted):

```
your_df.to_csv('some.txt', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems it was easier than I thought, I was focusing on delimiter, instead on escape chars.

This worked in my case:

```
new_f.to_csv("output.csv", sep=',', escapechar=' ', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL, index=False)
```